# custom number format in excel for disk or memory sizes

Tags: excel, graph

I'm trying to draw a graph where the y-axis is disk sizes.

And I have sizes ranging from 2 kilobytes through about 22 petabytes.

Represented as numbers that is ~2000 to 22e12

This looks pretty bad on a chart axis.

I could set the scale to "thousands" and then I'd be left with numbers between 2 and 22e9 and the reader is left to do the math that 22e9 (thousand) bytes is 22 petabytes and stuff like that.

But that's not intuitive.

So I tried a custom format.

I know that I can do

[Red][>1000000000];[Blue][>1000000]

but only two can be provided in this way.

I also know that I can do stuff for positive, negative and zero as well.

But is there a way in which I can accomplish the following:

(a) cell values are numbers, sizes in bytes, kilobytes or some such unit

(b) graph shows y axis with these numbers

(c) y-axis is logarithmic (very important)

(d) the y-axis labels are converted to K, M, G or P bytes as appropriate

---

If you think you have a solution, please verify it with this sample data:

1990, 2050

1992, 21246

1993, 208557

1996, 20971520

2000, 306184192

2012, 1.75922E+14

Your graph should be an X-Y Scatter (with lines)
Your graph should include the numbers in the first column as the x-axis on a linear scale
Your graph should include the numbers in the second column as the y-axis on a logarithmic scale
Your graph should have y-axis legends like "1K", "10K", "100K", "1M", "10M", "100M", ... "1P" and so on at the appropriate points.

---

This same solution would also be obviously applicable for money, where you want to show numbers in thousands, millions or billions with the appropriate suffix and a small number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to convert a string value in the form 99.9G to 99.9E^9 value

```
=CHOOSE(SEARCH(RIGHT(B5),"kMG"), 10^3,10^6,10^9)*VALUE(LEFT(B5,LEN(B5)-1))
```